# ASP.Net Core `UseAuthorization` not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code in my `Configure` method that is giving a warning:

[image: AuthzWarning]

It says:

> The call to UseAuthorization should appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(..) for authorization to be correctly evaluated.

It clearly is between those calls.  I would assume that it is mistaken and move on, but when I call my service operations I get this error:

[image: AuthzError]

The code will not run because it thinks that my `UseAuthorization` is not between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`.

I am stumped!  Not sure what I need to change to make this work.  Any advice on what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of asp.net core do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that higher up in the `Configure` method I had this:

```
app.UseMiniProfiler()
      .UseStaticFiles()
      .UseRouting()
      .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
          endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
      });
```

I ignored it because I thought it was all configuration for `UseMiniProfiler`, but it was actually chaining off the `app` to call `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` right in a row!

Removing those calls fixed it!